# How does Drupal 7 Load its Modules

Tags: 7

I'm debugging a Drupal 7 system I didn't setup, and I'm trying to understand how Drupal loads its modules.

This system appears to have modules nested within one other -- here's one example.

```
modules/custom/modulename/modulename.info
modules/custom/modulename/modulename.install
modules/custom/modulename/modulename.module
modules/custom/modulename/modulename_statistics/modulename_statistics.drush.inc
modules/custom/modulename/modulename_statistics/modulename_statistics.inc
modules/custom/modulename/modulename_statistics/modulename_statistics.info
modules/custom/modulename/modulename_statistics/modulename_statistics.module
```

It appears there's one module named `modulename`, and inside this module there's another named `modulename_staticstics`.

Is this a "legal/normal" setup?  Does nesting one module within another confer any special features between the two modules?  Where in the drupal source code are modules searched for/loaded?  Is there any canonical piece of documentation that covers how module loading works? (my googling didn't turn up a lot)

(experienced software engineer here, but only passingly familiar with Drupal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a "legal/normal" setup?

It's perfectly legal, and yes it's normal for modules that need or want to break their functionality down that way.

> Does nesting one module within another confer any special features between the two modules?

No, they’re just standard modules.

> Where in the drupal source code are modules searched for/loaded?

I think this is pretty much exhaustive for Drupal 7:

- /modules/**
- /profiles/*/modules/**
- /sites/*/modules/**

> Is there any canonical piece of documentation that covers how module loading works?

I wouldn't have thought so - following the code is probably the best way to understand how it works. Core is pretty well commented.

Comment: Thanks @clive, great answer.  One follow up question -- do you know where in the source module scanning kicks off? i.e. where's a good place to start a spelunking journey.

Comment: Pleasure - It's [`drupal_system_listing`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_system_listing/7.x) which does the scanning, happily it seems to be very well documented so that would be a good place to start